# What causes MalformedParameterizedTypeException? from camel-context.xml spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm having to upgrade an old code base due to flagged security violations from Nexus.
I've upgraded Spring from 4.2.2.RELEASE to 5.3.20 and camel from 2.18.0 to 2.25.2.
Using Java 8.
This was written years ago by contractors and I unfortunately inherited it with very little knowledge transfer. So if you ask, "why is..." I will probably have no idea. It's a batch system to process emails that's been running for years.

I'm just running this locally for now via a .bat file on my Windows machine. I'm having to export all the dependencies via maven-dependency and then reference that in the classpath in the .bat file. Not sure if that matters.

This error happens upon startup.

Edit: I originally had this titled referencing updating to Spring 5. But I have reverted those changes, gone back to Spring 4 and a slightly earlier minor version of camel, reverted as many changes as I can to get back to the original working baseline, and am still getting this same error on startup. The stacktrace does indeed make it look like it can't parse the camel-context.xml, but there's almost no changes in that now. In fact the only change is correcting a mis-spelled bean id, which I have also changed in the corresponding java file which references that bean by @Autowired.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [camel-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [app-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [camel-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
```

Here is the pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.foo.email</groupId>
    <artifactId>EntSendEmail</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>EntSendEmailBatchService</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Email Batch Service</name>

<properties>
    <spring-version>5.3.20</spring-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.3.28.Final</hibernate-version>
    <camel.version>2.25.2</camel.version>
    <log4j.version>2.17.2</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
    <cxf.version>3.4.3</cxf.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>EntSendEmail-Interface</groupId>
        <artifactId>EntSendEmail-Interface</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-sql</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
        <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Camel Quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.50-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockrunner</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper-el</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockrunner-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jboss/jboss-j2ee -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper-el</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper-el</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mockrunner</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockrunner-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper-el</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>jasper</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasper</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>EntSendEmailBatch</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <!-- <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes> -->
            <excludes>
                <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
                <!-- Since separating lib/*.properties from the jar file --> 

                <exclude>flib/</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- Included source code in the jar -->
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libMD2</outputDirectory>
                  <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                  <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                  <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
      </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                <includes>com/foo/email/ffdb/**/*.java</includes>
                <configLocation>src/main/resources/ES_CheckStyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>

                <includes>
                    <include>com/foo/email/ffdb/**/*.java</include>
                </includes>
                <configLocation>src/main/resources/ES_PMDRule.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
        
                        <executions>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                        <destFile>${project.basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                        <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                            runtime agent. -->

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                    after unit tests have been run. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-site</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->

                        <dataFile>${project.basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                        
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/coverage-reports</outputDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <!-- report and check -->
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                        
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/foo/email/ffdb/listener/*.class</exclude>                          
                        </excludes>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>CLASS</element>
                                
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.00</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/properties</outputDirectory>   <!-- output directory -->
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <!-- source directory -->
                                <directory>${basedir}/config/lib</directory> 
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes> 
                                    <include>*.properties</include> 
                                </includes>  <!--Only those files will be included -->
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/config</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <includes> 
                                    <include>fdr/*.properties</include> 
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the spring-context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
">
```

```
<!-- reading property file from classpath -->
<context:property-placeholder location="lib/*.properties" />

<bean id="emailProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>lib/*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.foo.email.ffdb.bean.FireFrgtWebSrvc</value>
            <value>com.foo.email.ffdb.bean.FireFrgtWebSrvcExcp</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Database -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:resultsMapCaseInsensitive="true" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Bean creation -->
<bean id="entSendEmailDBService" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.service.EntSendEmailDBService" />
<bean id="emailRequestDAO" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.dao.EmailRequestDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="entSendEmailRR" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.emailrr.EntSendEmailRRImpl" />
<bean id="entSendEmailAsyncService" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.async.EntSendEmailAsyncService" />
```

Here is the camel-context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security" 
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
  http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
">

<!-- ================================== -->
<!-- Define camel context -->
<!-- ================================== -->
<camel:camelContext id="camel" trace="false">
    <camel:propertyPlaceholder id="queriesConfig"
        location="lib/queries.properties" />
    <!-- Location for route scan -->
    <camel:package>com.foo.email.ffdb.listener</camel:package>
</camel:camelContext>

<!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
<bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="fireForgetServiceMapper" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.listener.FireForgetServiceMapper" />
<bean id="emailDBProcessor" class="com.foo.email.ffdb.listener.EmailDBProcessor" />

<!-- Database -->
<!-- <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:resultsMapCaseInsensitive="true" />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean> -->
```

Comment: It seems not to be able to parse camel-context.xml or am I mistaken? Is there a stack trace or is the error message everything it outputs?

Comment: There is a massive stack trace that I can't even get all of; and yes, it looks like it happens while parsing camel-context.xml; I have tried online validators for that and spring-context and both validate; and I haven't changed hardly anything in them; no idea why it wouldn't be able to parse it

Comment: One thing you can try to do is to debug the process, there is a chance that you will be able to get more out of the debug stack variables than there is logged. For that, I believe you have to launch the app with the debug agent like described here https://www.baeldung.com/java-application-remote-debugging#launch-command and then connect to the port you choose using remote debug option in the Intellij if you use Intellij. Can you show your bat script?